# Using Redemption with Outlook 2016 - "Could not find the store DN" with GetSharedMailbox

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-redemption

I had piece of code that was working perfectly until earlier this week, when I changed my domain password. After that, when trying to open a shared mailbox using `GetSharedMailbox`, I receive the error `Could not find the store DN`. Now, the really weird thing is that this only happens on one machine (unfortunately, the machine I really need it to run on). It works fine on my development laptop. Both machines have been rebooted, and logged back in repeatedly since then.

Both machines are logged into a Windows AD domain, under my account, and have no problems accessing other domain resources. I can open Outlook on the problem machine with no problem, and view both my personal inbox and the shared mailbox. Remote debug on the problem machine shows that it's opening a connection to Exchange ok (`rdo.Logon` works, and I can walk through its objects). The error is thrown when I try to open the shared mailbox.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

```
Try
    Dim rdo as RDOSession = New RDOSession

    rdo.Logon()
    Dim sharedBox As RDOStore = rdo.GetSharedMailbox("SharedMailbox@domain.com") 'Throws error here
    inbox = sharedBox.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mailbox: {0} ({1})", sharedBox.Name, sharedBox.EntryID))

    ' Do a bunch of stuff with inbox.Items

    Catch err As Exception
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(err, TraceEventType.Error, "Error connecting to mail server")

End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

The error usually means that Redemption does not have the credentials to retrieve autodiscover XML and configure the connection to the delegate mailbox. If you were using `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` instead of `Logon`, Redemption would have used the specified credentials. Otherwise you can cache the credentials using `RDOSession.Creadentials.Add`.